# Module not found - Caffine, Maven, module-info

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, module

I'm playing around with module-info, in order to obtain strong encapuslation.

I'm trying to access the module which is exposed here: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/caffeine/src/main/java/module-info.java

However, for me it says it can't find the module:

```
module stock.core {
    requires com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache;
}
```

with the error:

> Module not found: com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache

It's included in my dependencies:

Parent:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

        <caffeine.version>3.1.6</caffeine.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Internal dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
                <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
                <version>${caffeine.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Child pom:

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Internal dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any help is appriciated!

First I tried to google, and I found out I had to add the library to my class path, so I modified the parent POM including the maven-dependency-plugin. Then I tried adding the dependency into the Child POM as well. Then I tried looking into the github repo to make sure I had the correct package path to the module.

I've tried mvn install, but I just get an error that it can't find the module.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try reimporting maven depency
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF9yB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing your module-info to

```java
module stock.core {
  requires com.github.benmanes.caffeine;
}
```